# How to call a microservice to fetch data in spring webflux

Tags: spring, webclient, spring-webflux

I want to call a microservice from another service using webclient in spring flux. But, I am not able to write the code properly. Can you please suggest how to call another service. Please find my code as below.

I need to call the below service

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> load(ServerRequest res){
    String c1name = res.pathVariable("cust");
    String c2name = res.queryParam("cl").orElse("");
    String oname = res.queryParam("ol").orElse("");
    return res.body()
}
```

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> ftpFileSend(MultipartFile fileData, String cust, MultiValueMap<String,String) qpar {
    MultiValueMap<String,String> qpar=new LinkedMultiValueMap<String,String>();
       qpar.add("name","spring");
    MultiValueMap<String,Object> body=new LinkedMultiValueMap<String,Object>();
    String url="http://localhost:8088/"+ cust+"/load";

    try {
        body.add("file", fileData.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return Mono.error(e);   // <-- note how to create an error signal
    }


    return webClient
                .post()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(url).queryParams(qpar).build() )
                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(body))
                .retrieve()
                .toBodilessEntity();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm it would be great if you have provided some error logs or so. Anyway if you want to create a multipart body there is a builder, `MultipartBodyBuilder` (in org.springframework.http.client.MultipartBodyBuilder).

Example usage is as follows,

```
MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
builder.part("file", new MultipartFileResource(fileData));
MultiValueMap<String, HttpEntity<?>> multipartBody = builder.build();
```

Then use this `multipartBody` in webClient call.

```
return webClient
    ...
    .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(multipartBody))
    .retrieve()
    .toBodilessEntity();
```